# Efficient way to count number of arithmetic progression on coloring of $\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: coloring, arithmetic-combinatorics

Consider a coloring of $\mathbb{N}$ with two colors. How many monochromatic arithmetic progressions of a fixed length $m$ (i.e. numbers of the form $a+nd$ are colored the same) are there in the subset $\{1,2, \cdots, k\}$?

I have counted this for a few small values of $k$ by hand and it seems very complicated to count this in general due to the large number of overlaps.
Is it possible to generalize this to any number of colorings? I would also be interested in an asymptotic answer. Note: This relates to Van der Waarden's Theorem.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Are you just asking for an algorithm to count monochromatic APs in a specific coloring?  Why do you call it "very complicated"?  How long does a progression need to be for it to count?  Does it have to be maximal?  If so, then maximal with regard to extension, or with regard to inclusion?

Comment: Sorry, hopefully my edits will clear things up.

Comment: Thanks, it definitely helps to know you are interested in a fixed length.  There are only about $O(k^2/m)$ possible arithmetic progressions of length $m$.  Can you explain where the complication is?  What are the overlaps you're referring to?

Comment: Have you answered it yet?